# MySQL query for multiple counts returned for variable date ranges

Tags: mysql, date

I'm a SQL novice who has taken apart from a number of examples that pertain to what I am trying to get, but can't seem to put together all of the pieces, or even confirm if it is doable in one query. My example data structure is:

**Table**: *user*
**Fields**: *'id'* (integer) and *'start_date'* (date in YYYY-MM-DD format)

I'm trying to write a single query to return a listing of the count of members ('id') where their 'start_date' falls within the last fiscal year of June 1 - May 31. However, more than that I would like to return with a listing of previous fiscal years as well. The best I've been able to piece together is:

```
SELECT COUNT(user.id) As "Total Members" FROM user WHERE user.start_date BETWEEN '2010-06-01' and '2011-05-31' UNION
SELECT COUNT(user.id) FROM user WHERE user.start_date BETWEEN '2011-06-01' and '2012-05-31' UNION
SELECT COUNT(user.id) FROM user WHERE user.start_date BETWEEN '2012-06-01' and '2013-05-31' UNION
SELECT COUNT(user.id) FROM user WHERE user.start_date BETWEEN '2013-06-01' and '2014-05-31' UNION
SELECT COUNT(user.id) FROM user WHERE user.start_date BETWEEN '2014-06-01' and '2015-05-31' UNION
SELECT COUNT(user.id) FROM user WHERE user.start_date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' and DATE(CURDATE())
```

There are two issues with this, other than it seems inelegant. One is that while it does return the correct count in a column, I need to add a reference year in an adjacent column to get something along the lines of:

```
Fiscal Year | Total Members
----------------------------
    2011    |     ####
    2012    |     ####
    2013    |     ####
    2014    |     ####
    2015    |     ####
  CURRENT   |     ####
```

and the current query will only return the Total Members. And secondly, I am trying to generate this going about 40 years back (from 150,000+ member records) and I feel like there might be a better way by using a modifier on a year function of some kind instead of hard-coding the ranges (YEAR -1, YEAR -2, etc). Thinking that through logically, I also image potential problem with getting the correct reference returned with the correct range without getting overly complicated. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. I recognize my limitations, and if what I am looking to write is too complex to maintain I can stick with my existing example list (which goes back another 40 years) if need be. Thanks in advance to all that contribute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the count by year by doing some arithmetic and aggregation

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE_SUB(u.start_date, interval 5 month)) as fy,
       COUNT(*) As TotalMembers
FROM user u
WHERE user.start_date BETWEEN '2010-06-01' and '2011-05-31' UNION
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_SUB(u.start_date, interval 5 month))
ORDER BY fy;
```

I'm not sure what the "CURRENT" row is supposed to be.

If you want the total over all years, then you can use `with rollup`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(YEAR(DATE_SUB(u.start_date, interval 5 month)) as CHAR(25)),
               'Current') as fy,
       COUNT(*) As TotalMembers
FROM user u
WHERE user.start_date BETWEEN '2010-06-01' and '2011-05-31' UNION
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_SUB(u.start_date, interval 5 month)) WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY fy;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using a group by statement:

```
SELECT
To_number(to_char(user.start_date, 'YYYY')) AS YEAR
,COUNT(user.id) As "Total Members"
FROM user
GROUP BY
To_number(to_char(user.start_date, 'YYYY'))
```